# Is it possible to get the sitecore item from web database in CRM connector pipeline (batch pipeline) when we run it from CM server

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

We are running the sitecore CRM batch pipeline from CM server but required to get the item from web database when sync the sitecore item to CRM.

Comment: What Sitecore items you want to sync? I hope you want to sync Contact only.

Comment: Thanks swati, user can creating the "attachments" from portal so that these are creating in  web database instead of master. So we are required to sync these item from web database